# Biasing circuit schematic - MABC-001000-DP000L

Tags: bias, biasing

I am trying to design a bias controller circuit using **[MABC-001000-DP000L](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/249/MABC-001000-DP000L-540724.pdf)**. I am unable to find the full schematic of the same. Has any one used **[MABC-001000-DP000L](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/249/MABC-001000-DP000L-540724.pdf)** for designing bias circuit?

Edit:-
I have updated datasheet link

Comment: You should explain what is the function of an MABC-blah-blah-blah and also provide a link to its datasheet.

Comment: From the idiotically long PN I gather it's a Macom product, but beyond that, ... nothing.

Comment: Ask the vendor for it's datasheet.

Comment: @ThePhoton It is used for providing bias voltage for power amplifiers

Comment: What's missing from the schematics on pages 5 and 6 of the datasheet?

Comment: He has shown that gate voltage for DUT is directly given by pin numbers 1 and 3, but when I analyzed fig 3 and 4 on page number 6 he has used voltage followers for Negative gate voltage.

Comment: @ThePhoton they are kind of hiding little information on the datasheet of MABC-001000-DP000L. They have mentioned a few pins as "No connection" but they have used on the evaluation module. For example, pin 10 as noted as NC but has been used on the EV module. There is no separate datasheet for EVM. I have requested them for full schematic and BOM, til now they haven't responded back.

Comment: I have asked another question related to this with a detailed description. Link: - https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/512892/biasing-circuit-voltage-follower-circuit