# Biasing circuit - Voltage follower circuit

Tags: bias, biasing

I am using [MABC-001000-DP000L](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/249/MABC-001000-DP000L-540724.pdf), which is and Bias controller/sequencer. I am using this for Providing gate voltage and drain voltage to the [power amplifier](https://www.qorvo.com/products/d/da006704).

In the datasheet, it is mentioned that the module with combination of EVM can be used in two applications.

Application Option 1: Fixed negative gate biasing with pulsed drain biasing.

Application Option 2: Pulsed negative gate biasing with pulsed drain biasing.

I am trying to design both applications on a single board. The second option for future use.

For the 1st application option, he has mentioned a few pins as No connection and he has used those NC pins on the 2nd application.

[image]

**The issue I am facing:-**

They have used voltage followers for providing a low impedance output path for pin number 3(GCO).
I have reverse-engineered the Ckt from the below-attached image, but I am unable to identify the voltage follower they have used.

Pin number 2 of the voltage follower has been connected to pin number 2 (NC/GCP) of the Module. There has been no description of this pin number.

I am guessing these:-

1. Pin numbers 1 and 4 are connected together and output is provided through them.
2. Pin number 5 is +Ve supply hence connected to GND(Highest +Ve supply)?
3. Pin number 3 is connected to -8V
4. Pin number 2 is connected to pin number 2 of MABC-001000-DP000L, which I am unable to understand.

I have mailed component manufacturer regarding full schematic, till now I haven't heard from them.

Can anybody help me with this?

Thanks in Advance.

Low-resolution pic of EVM. I don't think it helps in any way.
[image]

[image: Layout diagram]

Layout Image

[image: SCHEMATIC FROM MACOM]

Comment: Specifically, what sort of help do you need?

Comment: @Andyaka I would like to know the circuit diagram of the voltage follower, he has used. Can we guess the +V, -Ve supply pins and +Ve and -Ve input pins from the image? So that I can use another known voltage follower chip.

Comment: Is anything missing in my question, which is making others stop answering my question?

Comment: The question appears unanswerable in that if there was a circuit you'd post it but then you'd already know from the circuit what the voltage follower is. If there were pictures of a circuit board with the part on then surely you'd post those too. If the layout diagram you have posted contains the device in question surely you'd have put a pointer on that picture to the device in question. Basically, it seems inaccessible.

Comment: @Andyaka I have marked the voltage follower on the layout image

Comment: In neither data sheet is the term "EVM" used. Please get your question sorted - I'm not here to debug questions that can't be answered. I don't even know what EVM means (your term).

Comment: @Andyaka EVM - Evaluation Module.

Comment: [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CoBKh.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CoBKh.jpg)could anyone send me the schematic of MABC-001000-PB1PPR board and pcb files

Comment: this my email ssamadm123@gmail.com

Comment: @SamAdm  Datasheet here may help https://cdn.macom.com/datasheets/MABC-001000-DPS00L_tn.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although your assumptions were wrong and the spec is correct, I found it hard at first to understand because of lack of details.

*A full schematic, layout, and bill of materials are available upon request.*
Also, ask for details on an external layout for testing.

1. Pin 1 & 3 are connected to DUT input as the voltage follower (internal Op Amp)
   Pin 4 is the non-inverting input. from VR1 from -8 Vdc .
   Pin 6 is TTL input pulses to drive Q1 Pch to pull up the DUT
   DUT is the QPA1022 4W 8.5 –11 GHz GaN Power Amplifier shown in Fig 1 for North Side bias.  [image]
   [image]
2. Pin 8 = Vds= 50V  , Pin 7 = Gnd
3. Pin 5 = -8V, Pin 7 = Gnd

[image]

4. I see no evidence of pin 2 = NC connected to anything. **(external only) Most likely a Test Pin.** Perhaps why they said do not ground.
   Pin 6 is also NC but connected to pin 12, so I suppose those are interchangeable interconnects.

Comment: I received gerber data from MACOM support team. They have routed NC pins mentioned in pin configuration table. I have informed them. They said they will get back to me!

Comment: Did you try R testing that port with a DMM?  It is likely an internal test point.

Comment: I will try testing with DMM. I asked them for schematic, but they are saying it is in datasheet. Do you think that Figure 1 is the complete schematic for Fixed gate and pulsed drain biasing?

Comment: It looks like it.

Comment: I received schematic from MACOM and i have added a snap of the same. They are not providing output gate voltage from pin number 1 and 3, in turn they have connected pin number 1 to pin number 2 and this is fed to voltage followers.

Comment: May be they have used voltage followers for avoiding current loading. They haven't provided pin number 2 description in datasheet. I have asked for the same and reply from them yet

Comment: Why the concern if they say NC?

Comment: They have mentioned it NC but in schematic they have used those pins

Comment: .that's for them to decide

Comment: Yes, but I am confused whether to use those pins or leave NC

Comment: Yes GCP, DFB and GSE seem to be undocumented.